# htaccess is not working in xampp in windows

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have edited the httpd.conf file like:

- changed to AllowOverride All

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shirts/$ /shirts/shirts.php
RewriteRule ^shirts/([0-9]+)/$ /shirts/shirt.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^receipt.php$ /receipt/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact.php$ /contact/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^shirts.php$ /shirts/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(shirts/[0-9]+)$ /$1/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^shirt.php$ /shirts/%1/? [R=301]
```

And the folder structure is like this:

shirts4mike
+ contact
+ css
+ img
+ inc
+ receipt
+ shirts
    |_ shirt.php
    |_ shirts.php
- .htaccess
- favicon.ico
- index.php

**I've tried many times, but it still showing index file does not exits, when I click the shirts in the home page.

I think xampp does ignore the .htaccess file.

If so, How should I fix?**

Comment: Have you included the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in your `httpd.conf` and have you restarted the service? You'll need to stop and start apache for any changes in `httpd.conf` to take effect.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Hi, I have already included it. and I found that if I put those files outside the shirts4mike folder, which means these files are in the root folder. It works, if not, not working...

Comment: Is `shirts4mike` your http root (ala `http://example.com` tries to load the `index.php` in `shirts4mike`?)

Comment: @Sumurai8 shirts4mike is in the htdocs folder, and the other files are in the shirts4mike folder

Comment: @Sumurai8 http://shirts4mike/shirts tries to load the shirts.php file

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you try to rewrite an url in a subdirectory, but it links to the http-root directory. You need to have the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory. You'll notice that a rule like `RewriteRule ^test$ /testing-is-fun` will match on an url `http://example.com/shirts4mike/test`, but rewrites to a file `testing-is-fun` in your http-root. We therefore need to fix the rewriting part of the rule.

The fix is having an relative url, instead of an absolute url. This can be done by removing the prefix `/`. For redirects, define `RewriteBase` with the subdirectory in it. I would add the `[L]` flag to every rule too. Your `.htaccess` should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shirts4mike/

RewriteRule ^shirts/$ shirts/shirts.php [L]
RewriteRule ^shirts/([0-9]+)/$ shirts/shirt.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^receipt.php$ receipt/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact.php$ contact/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shirts.php$ shirts/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(shirts/[0-9]+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^shirt.php$ shirts/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

As a side-note: I encourage you to do not use `[R=301]` while testing rewriterules. Some browsers cache a permanent redirect to increase performance. This is fine if your rules work as you expect them to work, but if that is not the case, further tests might link to your old page. This means when you change your `.htaccess`, you'll have to clear your cache to see the current situation.